# puppeteer take a screenshot after an exposed function has been called

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, puppeteer

I'm trying to use puppeteer to navigate to a page, wait for the webapp to reach a specific state, take a screenshot and exit. When the SPA is in the state that I want to take a screenshot of, it calls a function. I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around async js code.

My code looks as follows:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const url = 'http://example.com/';
const width = 300;
const height = 250;
const path = '/vagrant/tmp/screenshot.jpg';

async function takeScreenshoot(url, width, height, path) {
    "use strict";

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: width, height: height});

    await page.exposeFunction('interestingFunction', (async data => {
        console.log('Interesting function has been called. Taking a screenshot now.');
        await page.screenshot({path: path});
        await browser.close();
    }));

    await page.goto(url);
}

(async () => {
    "use strict";
    await takeScreenshoot(url, width, height, path);
})();
```

But when I call `screenshot.js`, I get warnings about an unhandled promise saying "Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed."

```
node --trace-warnings screenshot.js

Interesting function has been called. Taking a screenshot now.
(node:2572) Error: Protocol error (Runtime.evaluate): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
    at Session.send (/vagrant/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:167:29)
    at Page._onConsoleAPI (/vagrant/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:296:20)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:2572) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    at emitWarning (internal/process/promises.js:78:15)
    at emitPendingUnhandledRejections (internal/process/promises.js:95:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

If I remove the `await browser.close()` from line 18, there is no warning, but the script never finishes.

Now, the `interstingFunction()` does a little bit more but it is safe to expose it to the window for the webapp. I just tried to give an example of a minimal script above that still fails.

I'm using node v8.5.0.

Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: Your `page.goto(url)` call seems to be misplaced.

Comment: I'm following the example from https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/examples/custom-event.js to first expose the function and then go to the page. Please also note that the `await browser.close();` happens in a callback that will be called in a couple of seconds after the app loads, so it shouldn't really matter.

Moving `await page.goto(url);` didn't silence the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is some caller of that function and you do not need to call it by yourself with evaluate.

Imo, browser.close should be moved to the very end and go to before expose function. As far as read in documentation exposeFunction if returns a promise it will be awaited. in the end async / await is sugar for promises

```
await page.exposeFunction('interestingFunction', (async data => {
    console.log('Interesting function has been called. Taking a screenshot now.');
    await page.screenshot({path: path});
    await browser.close();
}));

await page.goto(url);
```

And that's my whole example

```
const url = 'http://example.com/';
const width = 300;
const height = 250;
const path = './screenshot.jpg';

async function takeScreenshoot(url, width, height, path) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load'});

    await page.exposeFunction('jjj', (async () => {
        console.log('Interesting function has been called. Taking a screenshot now.');
        return await page.screenshot({path: path});
    }));

    await page.evaluate(async () => {
      const myHash = await window.jjj();
    });

    await browser.close();
  }

(async () => {
    await takeScreenshoot(url, width, height, path);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! Yes, I'm not calling `interestingFunction()` myself. Unfortunately, your proposed solution returns without waiting for the the exposed function to be called at least once and therefore does not take any screenshots. That's the reason behind trying to close the browser within the callback in my original example.